# Add AD user to group when creating the user?

Tags: powershell

I've seen multiple examples on adding a user to a group after creation, but not at the time of creation. Is that possible?  Currently, I have something like this: (most attributes removed for simplicity)

```
$user = New-ADUser -Name "person" -Path "OU=test,OU=myorg" -Office "home" -samAccountName "snuffy.john" -PassThru

if ($user){
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity mygroup -Members $user.samAccountName
}
```

This causes two calls to the ldap server for each user added and I'm trying to prevent that as I have many thousands of users and the script takes a long time to run.  I've checked MS docs but didn't see anything. If it's not possible, it is what it is. Thought I'd try asking at least. I also just started using powershell last week.

Answer (score 0):

You may turn your thinking. with thousands of users I would do it like this.

First create all users.

Then get them by Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=test,OU=myorg"  (or maybe Filter the CreatedDate Attribute to get all new users)

After getting the users try to filter them for the groups you want to put them into and use the [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) cmdlet, which accepts an array of ADPrincipals for parameter "-members".

This will speed up your code.

Comment: Once created, it'd be impossible to filter them out from the existing users without looking up each by name. I could push $user into a List covert it to an array at the end and pass that. I just wonder how efficient increasing a list 12k times would be.